# android 11 scoped storage permission is not being handled. How to take parent folder permission and get data from child folder

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions, user-permissions, android-11

The Problem is here that I have taken persistent permission for the media folder now I want to get data from the child folder a  media --> com.whatsapp -->WhatsApp-->Media -->.Statuses

here is the code for the scope storage permission of the media folder which is successfully I have got

```
    private fun checkWhatsAppPermissionFor11Plus() {
            // Choose a directory using the system's file picker.
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
            // Optionally, specify a URI for the directory that should be opened in
            // the system file picker when it loads.
            val waStatusUri =
                Uri.parse("content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary/Android/media/document/primary/Android/media")
            if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, waStatusUri)
            }
            super.startActivityForResult(intent, 1001)
        }

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == 1001) {
            val treeUri = data!!.data
            contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(
                treeUri!!,
                Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
            )
            val editor = getSharedPreferences("status", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
            editor.putString("uri", treeUri.toString())
            editor.apply()
        }

    }
```

here is the code whereby using document tree URI I'm trying to get data but am not able to get

```
val docsFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(requireContext(), Uri.parse(uri+"%2Fcom.whatsapp%2FWhatsApp%2FMedia%2F.Statuses"))
```

here Uri is a persistent permission Uri up to the media folder

Please help out me if you have any idea about this if there is any confusion ask me I will explain more

Comment: `have taken persistent permission for the media folder ` What kind of persistent permission? And when and where did you do that? And how did you determine that folder? What is this about?

Comment: `the scope storage permission` What is a scoped storage permission? Never heard of

Comment: Storage Access permission Google introduces for android version 11+ devices. see above checkWhatsAppPermissionFor11Plus() method .

Comment: Such answers dont bring you any further. Sorry. Such a permission is unknown and never introduced.